# how to make 'ngs-java' in linux?

Tags: java

I want to install 'ngs' through the below instruction:

https://github.com/ncbi/ngs/wiki/Building-and-Installing-from-Source

In step 5 (Make each of the sub-projects) I tried to make ngs-java based on the below code:

```
make -C ngs-java
```

But I got bellow error:

```
make: Entering directory '/home/genetic/ncbi/ngs/ngs-java'
*** File 'Makefile.config.linux.x86_64' is missing. Please run ./configure
make: *** [/home/genetic/ncbi/ngs/ngs-java/Makefile.rules:72: Makefile.config.linux.x86_64] 
Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/genetic/ncbi/ngs/ngs-java
```

in ngs-java folder, I ran ./configure then I got below result:

```
Configuring NGS-JAVA package
checking system type... Linux
checking OS distributor... Ubuntu
checking machine architecture... x86_64
checking for supported architecture... x86_64 (64 bits) is supported
checking for supported OS... Linux (linux) is supported
checking for supported tool chain... jdk tool chain is supported
checking for javac... no
configure: error: 'javac' cannot be found
```

then I installed java. now when I ran java -version and got below result:

```
 openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04
 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04)
 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

After that I set path of java enviroment variable:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

but when I ran

> ./configure

in ngs-version I see again error about javac.

I appreciate if anybody his/her comment for solving this error with me.

Comment: `Please run ./configure` so please add the results of that command. You are getting an error there. Most likely you do not have javac (ie the java compiler) installed and you need that to use "ngs-java".

Comment: Dear @rinzwind based on your comment I ran ./configure and added the result of that as completed material in the post. I appreciated if you share your comment with me.